# Show the value returned from the method on the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oop, asp.net-core

**Model**

```
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int MaxSpeed(int speed)
    {
        return speed * 0.8;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    Car car = new Car();
    car.Brand= "ferrari-2020";
    car.Price = 50000;
    car.MaxSpeed(450);

    return View("Index", car);
```

**View**

```
@model Car

<div class="text-center">
   @Model.Brand
   @Model.Price

   How do I show the value returned from the controller?
   @Model.MaximumHiz()
 </div>
```

I can assign method to a variable and show it on the View, but how can I do it differently?

[image: Error]

Comment: You required an integer as a input for the MaxSpeed Function, but haven't given that input.

Comment: If I value MaxSpeed on View, it's on the screen, but I gave the Controller 450 for MaxSpeed. How can I show you that?

Comment: Why not assign them like the other values? `car.MaxSpeed = 450;`

Comment: Yes, as  @MathewHD said, You can create a Property for MaxSpeed instead of function.

Comment: I'm creating simple examples because I'm new. 
If I want to take a different process on the returned value
And if I want to use function for it, how do I do it? 
I changed MaxSpeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create MaxSpeed as a property with backing field

```
private int _maxSpeed;
public string Brand { get; set; }
public int Price { get; set; }

public int MaxSpeed
{
    get => (int) (_maxSpeed * 0.8);
    set => _maxSpeed = value;
}
```

and then set it with `car.MaxSpeed = 450;`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure, what you are trying to do differently, but in principle you can assign values to the model and use them to render the view.
The view itself does not know about the controller, so you can only render values from the model. From your screenshot: you are missing the speed parameter to call the method *MaximumSpeed(100)*.

Comment: I don't want to value MaxSpeed in View.
I want to show the value 450 given to MaxSpeed in the controller. I hope I made myself clear